# Sublime Text3 build error - Python not detected

Tags: python, sublimetext3

I'm receiving the error "Python was not found but can be installed from the Microsoft Store: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?linkID=2082640 [Finished in 0.3s]" when trying to run

```json
{
    "cmd": ["python3", "-u", "$file"],
}
```

I'm very new to python and I've tried other solutions on here with no effect. I'm also running on a windows 10 PC and made sure to add python 3.9 to path during installation. Sublime 3 worked fine initially, but after a using it a couple of times it started showing the error above. Could it be that I'm using a free version of Sublime?

Comment: Goto tools, build with> then select python. If it still doesn't work then uninstall python, download and install an earlier version of python like 3.7, and select custom installation, make sure everything is selected. Then goto tools> Build System> Python3. And Tools> Build with> Python

Comment: @shakhyar.codes why would installing an earlier version of Python change anything?

Comment: Have you tried using the Python build system that's already available under **`Tools → Build System → Python`**? How did you install Python originally?

Comment: Because latest version might still have some bugs, 3.7 is used all over the world widely, so sublime might needs update to build the latest version. But I would suggest not using the sublime build, as you should run the script from command prompt or terminal, which is better

Comment: @MattDMo I do have it selected as Tools → Build System → Python. I also installed python by running the setup downloaded from the website and ran it through the recommended setup adding python to path.

Comment: @shakhyar.codes "Because latest version might still have some bugs, 3.7 is used all over the world widely, so sublime might needs update to build the latest version. But I would suggest not using the sublime build, as you should run the script from command prompt or terminal, which is better" - works fine this way, but really hoping to resolve this too, maybe achieve some sense of accomplishment and learn something lol

Comment: @MattDMo I checked again and it works if I run the default build system 'Tools → Build System → Python'. Any idea why it won't run the python3 build code?

Comment: @reubenf It won't run your `python3` build system because the binary that comes with the Python.org distribution is called `python.exe`, not `python3.exe`.

Comment: @shakhyar.codes There's absolutely nothing wrong with the Python distribution itself. It's built automatically, *exactly the same way*, for every single release, whether it's a new minor version or a point release. 3.9 already had several alpha, beta, and release candidate releases before 3.9.0, so your argument simply doesn't make sense. It also doesn't make any sense to not use Sublime's built-in build systems.

Comment: The reason this fails is that as mentioned, the python you installed is named `python`, but WIndows 10 ships with a stub version of `python3.exe` that tells you how to install Python using the Windows 10 store, so people that follow instructions to run `python3` when it's not installed will get a useful message and help installing it instead of just "no such command" errors.

Answer (score 2):

First check if you can open python from a command prompt:

1. Win+R
2. Type `python` and press enter.

If python is open then try to add your custom `.sublime-build` for python:

1. In sublime go to Tools > Build System > New Build System...
2. Write this on that file:

```json
{ 
    "shell_cmd": "python \"$file\""
}
```

3. Save it with extension `.sublime-build`

I believe this is the simplest `.sublime-build` for python. When you press `Ctrl+S` to save it sublime will show you your sublime user folder. Save it right there with the name you want.

Then you will see it on Tools > Build System.

For more information see [Sublime Build System Documentation](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/build_systems.html)

Comment: There is already a `Python.sublime-build` that ships with Sublime. Why are you recommending making a new one with fewer features like error messages? Also, when you run Python from Sublime, you need to use the `-u` flag.

Comment: I recommended this because it is simple it's just running the program without making any regex match and that other stuff. Also `-u` is not completely necessary (it is just to force the `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` to to be unbuffered), I have used that specific build a lot of time.